# How to do something when a dynamically added button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to, in code, create a new button dynamically at run-time and add it to my form.  When I click the new button, I need it to do something.  For a normal button that I draw on the form at design-time, I would just do something like this:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Process.Start("")
End Sub
```

But, in this case, where I am creating a new button from within the click event of another button, I don't know how to assign functionality to it when it get's clicked.

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but I _think_ you are looking for [`AddHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx), e.g. `AddHandler Button4.Click, Sub(s, e) Process.Start("")`.

Comment: I've updated the question to fix the tags and make what you are asking more clear.  However, since it was difficult to tell what you were really asking, I had to make some assumptions.  Please fix my edit if I misrepresented your actual question in any way.

Comment: Yea sorry for my bad english. The AddHandler is working, but it's not permanent. When I create a new button, I want than when I restart the program, the button will be still there. That can be possible ?

Comment: Yes.  The easiest way would be to store it as a setting/configuration in a file, and then each time the program starts up, it could load the settings and create the button(s) dynamically as necessary.

Comment: Waouw, that's the easiest way haha. Not possible to just add text in the code when pressing a button ? :/

Comment: Unless you start going down some advanced, unusual paths, no, that's not possible because, under normal circumstances, when the application is running, there is no code.  At that point, the code has already been compiled into a binary assembly, essentially as machine instructions, which cannot be modified at run-time (glossing over lots of technical details here).  That's not to say that there aren't ways to dynamically compile and run code at run-time, but for something simple, I'd never recommend them, especially not to a beginner.

Comment: Okay, & so what is the propertybinding that should I use ? Because i really have no idea about this :/

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new control, you need to add it to the `Controls` collection of your form (or to one of the container controls on your form).  For instance:

```
Dim myButton As New Button()
Me.Controls.Add(myButton)
```

However, to capture and handle the click event, you need to declare and event handler method and then wire it up using the `AddHandler` keyword.  For instance, if you had a method like this:

```
Private Sub MyClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Then you can add it as a handler for the button's `Click` event like this:

```
AddHandler myButton.Click, AddressOf MyClickHandler
```

However, anytime you do that, you should make sure that you remove the handler from the event, once it's no longer necessary, like this:

```
RemoveHandler myButton.Click, AddressOf MyClickHandler
```

VB.NET also provides the handy `WithEvents` keyword which, depending on your needs, may be easier for you to use.